# Heap corruption from memory allocation using malloc: why did it happen?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, memmove

Ok, I was trying to implement memmove just as a programming exercise, and I get a memory access violation in the memmove function when I try to use malloc. Here is the function:

```
//Start

void* MYmemmove (void* destination, const void* source, size_t num) { 

    int* midbuf = (int *) malloc(num); // This is where the access violation happens.
    int* refdes = (int *) destination; // A pointer to destination, except it is casted to int*
    int* refsrc = (int *) source; // Same, except with source
    for (int i = 0;num >= i;i++) { 
        midbuf[i] = *(refsrc + i); // Copy source to midbuf
    }
    for (int i = 0;num >= i;i++) { 
        refdes[i] = *(midbuf + i); // Copy midbuf to destination
    } 
    free(midbuf); // free midbuf 
    refdes = NULL; // Make refdes not point to destination anymore
    refsrc = NULL; // Make refsrc not point to source anymore
    return destination;
}
```

By the way, I am sort of a newbie to pointers, so don't be suprised if there is some mistakes.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You don't need to cast the return value of malloc, or in fact any void pointer into any other pointer type. Still looking at your code, just an FYI.

Comment: @Dan: That is not true for C++, and the question has C++ tag as well.

Comment: Well, C++ is for silly people. Although I didn't notice that.

Comment: @Dan: you do if the C++ tag is relevant...  scrat101: are you writing C or C++?  They are two different languages, and trying to learn both simultaneously is going to be hard.

Comment: memmove takes a number of bytes, but you are using ints.

Comment: The standard library implementation of `memmove` doesn't use an intermediate buffer. Also, setting `refdes` and `refsrc` to `NULL` at the end is pointless: the function is about to return, so they can't be used.

Comment: In addition to the `malloc` size problem, the comparison in the `for` loops is wrong; it should be `num > i`, not `num >= i`. And as a matter of style, `i < num` is the usual way of writing it.

Comment: This is in C++; that is why I use // comments; only reason I have the c tag is since I use C libraries. And @PeteBecker, I hate loose ends, so that is why I like setting pointers to NULL, even if they are about to be thrown out anyway.

Comment: @scrat101 - I hate redundant code, so if you worked for me, you wouldn't set those pointers to NULL. <g>

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please be careful with the other suggestions! The answer depends on how your memmove will be used. The other answers state you should change your malloc call to account for the size of an int. However, if your memmove function will be used to mean "move this number of *bytes*" then the implementation would be wrong. I would instead go about using char* as that takes care of several problems in one go.

Also, an `int` is typically 4 bytes, and `char` is typically 1 byte. If the `void*` address you receive is not word aligned (not a multiple of 4 bytes), you will have a problem: To copy an int that is not word aligned you will have to do more than one read and expensive bit masking. This is inefficient.

Finally, the memory access violation happened because you were incrementing your midbuf `int` pointer each time, and moving forward *4 bytes at a time*. However, you only allocated num *bytes*, and thus would eventually try to access past the end of the allocated region.

```
/** Moves num bytes(!) from source to destination */
void* MYmemmove (void* destination, const void* source, size_t num) { 

    // transfer buffer to account for memory aliasing
    // http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing_%28computing%29
    char * midbuf = (char *) malloc(num); // malloc allocates in bytes(!)
    char * refdes = (char *) destination;
    char * refsrc = (char *) source;

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
        midbuf[i] = *(refsrc + i); // Copy source to midbuf
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) { 
        refdes[i] = *(midbuf + i); // Copy midbuf to destination
    } 

    free(midbuf); // free midbuf
    // no need to set the pointers to NULL here.
    return destination;
}
```

By copying byte by byte, we avoid alignment issues, and cases where num itself could be not a multiple of 4 bytes (e.g. 3, so an int is too large for that move).

Comment: Thanks, I have seen people use char in memory reads and writes for similar reasons; was just not too sure to use it. Thanks for clarifying. :)

Comment: Oh and BTW my function works now thanks to the suggestions. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 3):

Replace the string with malloc with this one:

```
int* midbuf = (int *) malloc(num*sizeof(int));
```

The problem is that you allocated not `num` elements of int but `num` bytes.

Comment: If it's c casting return value of malloc is a bad idea. It can hide allocation failure

Comment: @fayyazkl: Uh how? The value would still be null.

Comment: Well, yes, this fixes the internal buffer overrun. But the code still copies more bytes than it's supposed to. The original `malloc` call was correct; it's the pointer types that are wrong.

Comment: @GManNickG If malloc is not correctly prototyped (which is often possible if you are building on an embedded platform with library compiling along), casting the return value won't fix anything. malloc() will still return int, and casting that int to an object pointer type isn't magically going to change it to a pointer. Casting malloc() will make the compiler think it's not broken, although it really is when an int is being returned.

Comment: @fayyazkl - it depends. <g> If an int and a pointer are the same size, the cast works just fine. That's the old C heritage from the days before function prototypes. On some systems these days an int and a pointer are different sizes, and the cast does, as you say, hide a problem.

Comment: @PeteBecker Yeah that's pretty common e.g. my x64 machine (ci7-2670 ubuntu 12.04) gives 8 byte pointer, 8 byte long and 4 byte int. There are many embedded architectures with less than perfect ports of gcc or other tool chains which are not forgiving on this. This is more like a coding guide line and treated as a bad practice similar to many others such as taking care of endianess in your code even when you are running on little endians and several others.

Comment: @fayyazkl - sorry, I wasn't clear enough: I agree that it's a bad practice. I was just trying to clarify where it comes from.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sure that's perfectly fine and i appreciate your explanation. If i read my comment above from the perspective of some one looking for the reason, it doesn't reveal that at all. This discussion makes it clear enough and would be helpful for any readers Thanks :)

Comment: @fayyazkl: That has nothing to do with your original comment, which was about allocation failure. Allocation failure != missing declaration.

Comment: @GManNickG perhaps i should have elaborated more. It is not necessary that every platform represents null by a zero. So if an allocation fails, it would return NULL, which depending upon platform when casted to pointer can result in a crash. Allocation failure is more likely to suffer compared to success when typcasted explicitly. Hope that helps.

Comment: @fayyazkl: I still don't follow. Casting `void*` to `T*`, as long as `T` isn't a function type, always works when working with null pointers. I'm well aware about null pointer representation being implementation-defined. And again, this has nothing to do with the function not being declared. I'm also aware of the argument that you shouldn't cast the result because it hides the implicit signature mistake, but I still don't see how it links to your original comment or this one. :/

Comment: @GManNickG The entire argument above is with the assumption that one can forget to include malloc's header. Now malloc is assumed to be an 'extern returning int'. If your int and pointer are of different sizes, the cast would result in truncation and some weird address. If malloc returns null which in case is represented by a special address, which typecasted to int might even give you a valid or wrong address. More importantly, it would pass next test of if (Returned pointer != NULL) despite having failed.

Comment: @fayyazkl: Yes. All I'm saying is your original comment mentions none of that.

Comment: I wrote "it can hide allocation failure". If i had given an explanation, that would have given details mentioned above. Moreover, i wanted to distinguish the fact that success in allocation might work or at least be caught earlier due to invalid address. Failure and still getting success on the if(NULL) check is still more puzzling and subtle.

Answer (score 1):

```
int* midbuf = (int *) malloc(num); // This is where the access violation happens.
int* refdes = (int *) destination; // A pointer to destination, except it is casted to int*
int* refsrc = (int *) source; // Same, except with source
for (int i = 0;num >= i;i++) { 
    midbuf[i] = *(refsrc + i); // Copy source to midbuf
}
```

You `malloc` only `num` bytes, but in the loop, you try to copy `num` `int`s. Since an `int` usually takes more than one byte, you're accessing out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

memory access violation?

You are trying to access memory you are not entitled to access.  Maybe you have a null pointer or the pointer is pointing into another program or the code segment.

Comment: If you have a pointer pointing to say, 0x00000000 and you access it and it gives you a memory access violation, then that is the pointer and where it is pointing to...specifically.  Note, it doesn't have to be 0x00000000, it could be any address outside of your program.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're mallocing `num` bytes into `midbuf`, and then copying `num` ints into it. Since an `int` is larger than a byte on most platforms, you have a problem. Change your `malloc` to `num*sizeof(int)` and you won't have that problem.

Comment: -1 - the third argument to `memmove` specifies the number of **bytes** to move. The `malloc` is correct; the pointer types are wrong.

Comment: as above - the answer is correct, depending on how you understand the question.

Comment: Well, only if MYmemmove is the same as memmove. One way or another, he has a problem.

Comment: @Dan - "I was trying to implement memmove just as a programming exercise".

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems to be looked at

**1. Memory space**

(provided that `MYmemmove` does a custom implementation to move `ints` as the question suggests)

```
    int* midbuf = (int *) malloc(num * sizeof(int));
```

`malloc` is byte based, and will allocate *num* bytes. `int *` is a pointer to `ints`. Meaning `midbuf[x]` will access the memory from `midbuf + sizeof(int)*x`. You want to allocate *num* `ints` instead (the size of an int depends on architectures, it is usually 4 or 2 bytes). Thus the `malloc(num * sizeof(int))`.

**2. Array indexes**

```
    for (int i = 0;num > i;i++) {
```

in C (and C++) arrays are 0-based, i.e. the first index is `0`. You did it correctly. But that means also that if you reserve *num* `ints`, the useable indexes will be from `0` to `num-1`. In your loops, `i` will vary from `0` to `num`, thanks to the condition `num >= i`, meaning you will access `num+1` items. So `num > i` (or `i < num`) would be a better `for` condition.

Comment: -1 - the third argument to `memmove` says how many **bytes** to move. The `malloc` call is correct; it's the pointer types that are wrong.

Comment: The actual `memmove` function moves bytes. It is not clear from the initial question that `MYmemmove` is not a custom version to move `ints` instead. I edited my answer to take this into account.

Comment: The above answer is correct when looking at the question: why did the memory violation happen? Pete is correct when it comes to "what is a proper way to implement mmove".

Comment: @ring0 - it is quite clear: "I was trying to implement memmove just as a programming exercise".

Answer (score -1):

```
#include <stdlib.h>  // did you included this?


void* MYmemmove (void* destination, const void* source, size_t num) { 

    char *Source = source, *Destination = destination;
    char *Middle = malloc( sizeof(char) * num );    // midbuf

    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++) { 
        Middle[i] = Destination[i]; // Copy source to midbuf
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++) { 
        Destination[i] = Middle[i]; // Copy midbuf to destination
    }

    free(Middle);                   // free memory allocated previously with malloc
    return destination;
}
```

Acces violation could occur because you didn't included libraries needed for malloc (standard c doesn't throw errors in your face if you forgot a function definition). You don't need to mark pointers as NULL since there's no garbage collection in C (pointers are just that - pointers. Addresses to a point in memory, not memory themselves).

think about pointers like

addres of pointer
0x1243               0x4221
Destination    ->    {some kind of data}

Destination = 0x1243
*Destination = whatever value is currently at addres 0x4221

You can't also index void pointers. You must first cast them to some type, so the compiler knows how much offset they need.

Destination[x] = *(Destination+x)

a char is 1 byte, so char pointer will really get moved by x bytes, but an int is 4 bytes, and an int pointer will get moved by 4*x bytes. Don't worry too much if it sounds technical, it'll be important when you'll get to something really low level ;)

Comment: -1 `memmove` works even when the two arrays overlap; this implementation will create nonsense in that case.